# Any number that i put in the textfield it appears in the label as 0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield, uilabel

i've been doing a thing here using objective-c, but i'm a beginner in this language, and that's what i did:

there is a class, named "firstviewclass", that is in the control of my first view, in this view there is a textfield that the user puts a number. the textfield is in the firstviewclass.h named "setNumber". There is another class, named "secondviewclass" that is in control of the second view, in this view there is a label that is in the secondviewclass.h, and i want that this label recive the value that the user put in the textfield from the first view, but when i test it on the iOS simulator any number that i put in the textfield it appears in the label as 0... I really don't know what to do!

My codes:

firstviewclass.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface firstviewclass : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *setNumber;

- (IBAction)gotonextview:(id)sender;

@end
```

secondviewclass.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "firstviewclass.h"

@interface secondviewclass : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelthatrecivesthetextfieldvalue;

@end
```

secondviewclass.m:

```
#import "secondviewclass.h"
#import "firstviewclass.h"

@implementation secondviewclass
@synthesize labelthatrecivesthetextfieldvalue;


-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    firstviewclass *object = [[firstviewclass alloc] init];

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", [object.setNumber.text intValue]];

    labelthatrecivesthetextfieldvalue.text = string;

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would strongly recommend not naming a property or instance variable `setSomething`. It will cause headaches for anyone reading your code because it will always look like you're trying to call a setter. Also, please do capitalize your class names.

Your actual problem is that in `viewDidLoad` you're creating an instance of `firstviewclass`, and then trying to get the value from setNumber. That is before the user had any chance to enter anything.

Also, the `setNumber` outlet in `firstviewclass` will probably be going nowhere anyway, since you're instantiating that class yourself, instead of loading the NIB.

---

Edit (ah, Storyboard, d'oh):

For Storyboard, you need to pass the setNumber text field's value to the second view.

First of all, remove the `firstviewclass *object = [[firstviewclass alloc] init];` line.

Then, in your first view controller's `prepareForSegue` method, you can pass the value of the `setNumber` text field to a property in your your second view controller, and use it from there (e.g. in `configureView`).

I recommend [working through Apple's Storyboard tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH1-SW1), it shows exactly what you need to do, step by step. The step you're having issues with right now, passing data to your next view controller, is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CustomizingDetailView/CustomizingDetailView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH5-SW4).

Comment: i don't know what is a NIB, when i started using Xcode, storyboard was already there... Sorry for my lack of knowledge in this area.

Comment: Please see the edits above. If you go through Apple's Storyboard Tutorial, things should become a lot clearer for you.

Answer (score 1):

in the viewDidLoad of secondviewclass, you are creating a new instance of firstviewclass, and then accessing the property of the label. Since you haven't set that to be anything, it will always return zero.

Can you post the implementation of the gotonextview method?

EDIT:

I think you need to be setting the label property from the first view controller. so in your gotonextview method, add this line:

```
secondviewclass.labelthatrecivesthetextfieldvalue.text = self.setNumber.text;
```

I admit I'm a little lost in your naming scheme but that might work.

Comment: i'm using storyboard, so the are nothing in the implementation, it only brings the user from a view to other with modal... i hope you understand, i don't know how to explain.

Comment: when i did it a error appeared: "Property 'labelthatrecivesthetextfieldvalue' on object of type 'secondviewclass'" what i did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

How are you initiating the setting of the label? From `viewDidLoad`? If so, then **0** would be correct because you have not set `object.setNumber.text` to anything. Also, you aren't carrying over the data from your first viewController. You need to let the second viewController know what the number is. Try setting this value in your `NSUserDefaults`, then in your second viewController, load that value from your defaults.

Comment: i'm new with objective-c and this iphone sdk, i don't know what are you talking about, i'm sorry...